# Ошибка в Android Studio build.gradle. Failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Помогите пожалуйста. При первом запуске Android Studio появляется ошибка Failed to resolve. Замена версии ничего не дает

[image: Failed to resolve]

Comment: А если ткнуть в первый предлагаемый фикс _Install Repository..._ ? И указывать версию зависимости с `.+` не рекомендуется. Лучше указывать конкретную версию.

Comment: Нажатие на первый фикс ничего не дает, AS не реагирует на это. Смена версии тоже ничего не дает.

Comment: А Вам нужна студия именно 2.3.3? Может новую лучше поставить https://developer.android.com/studio . Или попробуйте добавить репозиторий гугла в build.gradle уровня проекта https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven . Если не получится выкладывайте содержимое обоих build.gradle в вопрос текстом.

Comment: Не знаю, мне посоветовали именно эту версию. Спасибо за репозиторий. Пока ничего не выходит. Попробую ещё